# JavaScript cloning XML node problem

Tags: javascript, xml

This section of code is to first get the data and display the data from the XML file. After that there is a button below named submit. When I press submit, it calls the function `add()` and it will copy the first node from the XML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<table>
</tr class="top">
<td>ID</td>
<td>Orgin</td>
<td>Type</td>
<td>Color</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
  document.write("<tr class=a><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("orgin")[0].getAttribute("id"));
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("orgin")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("color")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");

function add()
{var id=document.getElementById('idProduct').value;
var time=document.getElementById('Time').value;
var org=document.getElementById('orgin').value;
var color=document.getElementById('color').value;
var type=document.getElementById('type').value;

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("test.xml"); //Problem happen here, the code doesn't functioning
oldNode=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('product')[1];
newNode=oldNode.cloneNode(true);
xml.Doc.documentElement.appendChild(newNode); 
}

</script>
<br>
Inputs:
<br>
Time: <input type="text" id="time"><br>
ID: <input type="text" id="idProduct"><br>
Orgin: <input type="text" name="orgin"><br>
Type: <input type="text" name="type"><br>
Color: <input type="text" name="color"><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="add()"></input>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Big5" ?>
<set>
  <product time="5">
    <orgin id="1">sony</orgin>
    <type>comp</type>
    <color>red</color>
  </product>
  <product time="6">
    <orgin id="2">apple</orgin>
    <type>others</type>
    <color>blue</color>
  </product>
</set>
```

Comment: Where is the function *loadXMLDoc* defined? It seems to me that at the point you call the function, *xmlDoc* is already an XML document. A couple of lines further down, you have `xml.Doc.documentElement` which probably should be `xmlDoc.documentElement`.

Comment: Also, you really should write the entire table as one string of HTML, document.writing it out in parts is a very bad idea - what is the HTML parser to make of the bits as each write finishes? Anyway, the HTML looks invalid.

Comment: Thanks . I have modified xml.Doc.documentElement. And i would like to know what does it mean for defining loadXMLDoc???

i am following the instruction here:

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_clone.asp

Comment: You call *loadXMLDoc* but don't define it (it probably throws a reference error that you are not reporting). The W3Schools example includes a file called *loadxmldoc.js* which I presume is where they define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the W3Schools loadxmldoc.js file:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Add that to your script block and it may start working (or get you a little further along).